# Notepad++ find between lines

Tags: notepad++, regex

I would like to find out if there are "duplicate" text-fragment between two specific lines.

For example i would like to find out that in the first "TestMethod" there is twice the "TC.Requirement" set.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [TestProperty(TC.Name, "")]
    [Description("A test for ")]
    [TestProperty(TC.InternalTcId, "2c80e355-c156-4fd1-ba10-bdfb50f67828")]
    [Owner("")]
    [TestProperty(TC.CreationDate, "")]
    [TestProperty(TC.Requirement, "1111")]
    [TestProperty(TC.PostCondition, "")]
    [TestProperty(TC.PreCondition, "")]
    [TestProperty(TC.Types, TCType.Normal_Case)]
    [TestProperty(TC.Requirement, "2222")]
    [TestProperty(TC.ReviewDate, "")]
    public void ATest()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(target);
    }


    [TestMethod()]
    [TestProperty(TC.Name, "")]
    [Description("A test for ")]
    [TestProperty(TC.InternalTcId, "8d00d256-86fe-4a08-864c-6f1bf38581ce")]
    [Owner("")]
    [TestProperty(TC.CreationDate, "")]
    [TestProperty(TC.PostCondition, "")]
    [TestProperty(TC.PreCondition, "")]
    [TestProperty(TC.Types, TCType.Normal_Case)]
    [TestProperty(TC.Requirement, "3333")]
    [TestProperty(TC.ReviewDate, "")]
    public void BTest()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(target);
    }
```

In the first TestMethod there is a doubled Requirement-aatribute, in the second TestMethod there isn't a second.

Could you help me find out the regex for that search?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Have you checked the Notepad++ plugin repository? Do you have Cygwin installed?

Comment: Hi, no Cygwin is not installed. What do I need it for? I am able to search text with Regex, but I am not able to create an appropriate Regex expression to find what I am looking for :-)

Comment: It's another way of working with text files. But you should try to do it with Regex, perhaps something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
TestMethod((?!TestMethod).)*Requirement((?!TestMethod).)*Requirement
```

Basically it uses negative look aheads to check that `Requirement` occurs twice WITHOUT any occurrence of `TestMethod` between them.

**Important:** Make sure that you have the `. matches newline` checkbox checked in the Notepad++ settings.